# Need link download Offline installer x11vnc for Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: debian-installer

I have problem:

[image]

I need link download offline installer for xubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386
→ x11vnc

[image: list file downloaded]

thanks

Comment: Please copy the text into the question so others can benefit from it. Images are difficult to search text from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you do not have an off-line installer, I mean, the package it self is the installer, what the apt is telling you is cannot resolve dependency by himself, as far as I know this is a common situation with .deb package and normally is fixed by run "apt -f install" command. But in your case seems you do not access to the repositories, so you have to download also libvncclient1 and libvncserver1. 
The most easy solution is to let machine access internet and run apt -f install, if you can't do that here you can find each dependency and install it:

- [tk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/tk/download)
- [libvncclient1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libvncclient1/download)
- [libvncserver1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libvncserver1/download)

In case more dependency will show up later you can search manually the packages in the [ubuntu repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

otherwise if dependency are too many to be managed manually you can consider create a temporary repository in an usb card.